# Need to add up number of dates within one year of a certain date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset: I need to calculate the number of ER Dates with a score of 1 that fall within 1 year of the Phenedate of that subject and phenedate.  So for subject 3 and phenedate 3v1, there are 2 ER dates with score of 1 within a year of 11/23/05, giving the score of 2.  Following this formula, there is 1 date for 3v2 (9/30/06), 4 for 3v3, 1 for 3v4, and 3 for 3v5.

```
PheneVisit  PheneDate   Score   ER Date
    N/A                   0       10/25/05    
phchp003v1  11/23/05      0
             N/A          1       5/5/06        
phchp003v2  5/10/06         
              N/A         0       6/22/06
              N/A         0       8/5/06
phchp003v3  8/9/06        
              N/A         1        9/30/06
              N/A         1        5/26/07
phchp003v4  2/7/14  
              N/A         1       10/13/14
              N/A         0       2/15/15
              N/A         0       3/5/15
              N/A         1       8/14/15
phchp003v5  8/17/15     
              N/A         0      10/11/15
              N/A         1      11/12/15
              N/A         0      11/26/15
              N/A         1      3/1/16
              N/A         1      4/14/16
```

This is the result I'm looking to get.  I'm not sure how to count iterate over the dates properly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Let me know if there is any confusion.

```
PheneVisit    Number of First Year 
               0
phchp003v1     2
               0
phchp003v2     1
               0
               0
phchp003v3     2
               0
               0
phchp003v4     1
               0
               0
               0
               0
phchp003v5     3
```

Comment: Can  you add code that generates your input dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston Apologies for the ignorance, but how should I go about generating that?  I have the dataframe in an excel sheet which i just copy pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `pd.IntervalIndex` and list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

inputtxt = StringIO("""
PheneVisit  PheneDate   Score   ER Date
N/A          N/A          0       10/25/05    
phchp003v1  11/23/05      0
N/A             N/A          1       5/5/06        
phchp003v2  5/10/06         
N/A              N/A         0       6/22/06
N/A              N/A         0       8/5/06
phchp003v3  8/9/06        
N/A           N/A         1        9/30/06
N/A           N/A         1        5/26/07
phchp003v4  2/7/14  
N/A           N/A         1       10/13/14
N/A           N/A         0       2/15/15
N/A           N/A         0       3/5/15
N/A           N/A         1       8/14/15
phchp003v5  8/17/15     
N/A          N/A         0      10/11/15
N/A           N/A         1      11/12/15
N/A           N/A         0      11/26/15
N/A           N/A         1      3/1/16
N/A           N/A         1      4/14/16
""")

df = pd.read_csv(inputtxt, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

df['PheneDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PheneDate'], format='%m/%d/%y')

df['ER Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ER Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

pi = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['PheneDate'], df['PheneDate'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1))
df['Number of First Year'] = np.sum(np.vstack([pi.contains(i) for i in df.loc[df['Score'] == 1, 'ER Date']]), 0)
df
```

Output:

```
    PheneVisit  PheneDate  Score    ER Date  Number of First Year
0          NaN        NaT    0.0 2005-10-25                     0
1   phchp003v1 2005-11-23    0.0        NaT                     2
2          NaN        NaT    1.0 2006-05-05                     0
3   phchp003v2 2006-05-10    NaN        NaT                     1
4          NaN        NaT    0.0 2006-06-22                     0
5          NaN        NaT    0.0 2006-08-05                     0
6   phchp003v3 2006-08-09    NaN        NaT                     2
7          NaN        NaT    1.0 2006-09-30                     0
8          NaN        NaT    1.0 2007-05-26                     0
9   phchp003v4 2014-02-07    NaN        NaT                     1
10         NaN        NaT    1.0 2014-10-13                     0
11         NaN        NaT    0.0 2015-02-15                     0
12         NaN        NaT    0.0 2015-03-05                     0
13         NaN        NaT    1.0 2015-08-14                     0
14  phchp003v5 2015-08-17    NaN        NaT                     3
15         NaN        NaT    0.0 2015-10-11                     0
16         NaN        NaT    1.0 2015-11-12                     0
17         NaN        NaT    0.0 2015-11-26                     0
18         NaN        NaT    1.0 2016-03-01                     0
19         NaN        NaT    1.0 2016-04-14                     0
```

Details:

- Create an interval index using `pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays` using
  PheneDate and `pd.DateOffset` with parameter `years=` to create a
  year interval.
- Filter dataframe for Score == 1 and check to see if those dates are
  inside the given range, pi defined above.
- Lastly, sum vertically to get the number of Trues in each Interval
  range.

Comment: Thank you that is a very interesting way, I understand what you are doing however It is returning this error ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DateOffset") to str``` I'm assuming it is because my dataset is larger and contains something that is messing it up.

Comment: You need to convert your PheneDates to datetime first. The error you are getting is stating that PheneDate is a string and it only wants to add strings and not DateOffsets.   if you convert PheneDates to datetime first, this error will go away.  `df['PheneDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PheneDate'], format='%m/%d/%y')` should do it, but maybe you some errors, try adding `errors='coerce'` a a parameter to_datetime.

Comment: Yes thank you I am now getting an output.  However, the output I'm getting is ```Number of First Year
0
15
0
26
0
0
36
``` 
for the first 3 phene visits.  I failed to mention that there are multiple subjects such as 003 and 004, so they should be grouped by overall subject, which may be what's giving these different numbers.

Comment: @Guitarman045 You need to create a new question with more expanded test data.  I am having hard time seeing what you're stating here.

Comment: Ok I just posted another question that will hopefully clarify, I went ahead and marked your answer as correct because it was helpful.  Thank you, if you wish to see the new question it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534020/how-to-calculate-number-of-dates-within-a-year-of-a-date-in-pandas